# NUL at the beginning of written file

Tags: writetofile, nul

I have the following question. When writing a String to a file the first character seems to be a Nul. I see that if I open the file with Notepad++, there is a black background where "NUL" is written in white. However, I don't really understand why this is happening. The String is transmitted from another device to a tablet running Android on it, afterwards the data should be written to a file. When debugging the code everything looks fine until I'll open the file.

Thanks and cheers
pingu

Comment: Please could you elaborate on your question and show us your code that is actually doing the writing to the file

Comment: Your string either starts with or consists solely of a null terminator. Inspect the string you're writing to the file with your debugger.

Comment: isn't your string( that you're writing to file ) initialized to null?